# Event listeners before ajax callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var startTimeout = function () {
            setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000);
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('mousemove', function () { globals.idleTime = 0; });
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('keypress', function () { globals.idleTime = 0; });
        };
        var timerIncrement = function () {
            Tools.getParameterFromDatabase('idleTime', function(idleTime) {
                globals.idleTime++;
                if (globals.idleTime > idleTime / 1000 - 1) {
                    doAction();
                }
            });
        };
```

doAction() method should fire when user does nothing for idleTime seconds - this idleTime is places in the database, so I have to load it with ajax.

The problem is that globals.idleTime is not setting to 0 with user action. Events seem to fire only after doAction() is being called.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set idleTime to 0 manually.

Comment: No I can not. It has to be set to 0 when user does some action.